# How to prevent dartfmt to leave the space between getter and setter

Tags: flutter, dart, dartfmt

This is what I want.

```
int _foo = 42;
int get foo => _foo;
```

But when I format the code using dartfmt, it changes to

```
int _foo = 42;

int get foo => _foo;
```

How can I prevent this behavior?

Comment: This is not a getter and setter but just a getter and an definition of an internal variable. Also, what version of Dart are you using? I can't seem to reproduce your issue.

Comment: I didn't know they were not getter-setters. How do a one look like? And I'm using Dart `2.7.2`.

Comment: Getter: `int get foo => _foo;` Setter: `set foo(int foo) => _foo = foo;`

Comment: And try use 2.10.4 and see if you can reproduce your issue.

Comment: @julemand101 Thanks for that pair. I used `2.10.4` and still the problem persist. I'm using Android Studio IDE (if that makes any difference)

Comment: Also actual getter-setter also seem to have the same issue.

Comment: Yes, that does make a difference since the Dart code formatting are different for Dart and Flutter. Have you tried with the `dartfmt` command from the Dart SDK?

Comment: @julemand101 Not yet, let me try.

Comment: You can see the relevant part of the Style guide here: "If no particular order is obvious, then the following order is suggested, with blank lines between each one" https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Style-guide-for-Flutter-repo#order-other-class-members-in-a-way-that-makes-sense

Comment: Nothing changed. Same code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225019/discussion-between-julemand101-and-idecode).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two types of formatting. One is regular formatting provided by the IDE, also known as `Reformat Code` and the other is provided by Flutter CLI, also known as `Reformat Code with Dartfmt`.

By default, when you press the keyboard shortcut <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>, it runs the former `Reformat Code` (which doesn't use `dartfmt` to format the code).

To fix this behavior, override keyboard shortcut in your IDE. Go to

```
File > Settings > Keymap > Editor Actions > Reformat Code with Dartfmt
```

and assign it the above mentioned shortcut.